# Onsen UI Back button not working when using tabbar

Tags: onsen-ui

I have modified my app to use the tabbar control and it's working as expected. However, the back buttons that worked before modification no longer work. Any ideas on what the issue might be?

Comment: It's quite hard to guess where is your problem if you don't provide any code. But well, `<ons-back-button>` is supposed to be used with `<ons-navigator>`, since it pops a page from the navigator's stack. Are you using an `<ons-navigator>` inside the tabbar?

Comment: No I am not using <ons-navigator> since it doesn't work with <ons-tabbar>. Your response prompted me to dig deeper into the docs and it looks like I am going to have to roll my own back button.